# Duplicate a linked list in python.I am not sure how to add a new empty node in the loop to link the last node

Tags: python

I am learning data structure, I have completed the preliminary linked list with spyder, but I want to copy this linked list and the result is 123123, I am not sure how to add a new empty node in the loop to link the last node

```
class Node():
 def __init__(self, data):
     self.next = None
     self.data = data
def Q2():
    class LinkList:
        def __init__(self):
            self.head=None
    
        def initList(self, data):
            self.head = Node(data[0])
            r=self.head
            p = self.head
            for i in data[1:]:
                node = Node(i)
                p.next = node
                p = p.next
            return r
            
        def printlist(self,head):
            if head == None: 
                return
            node = head
            while node.next != None:
                print(node.data,end='')
                node = node.next
            print(node.data,end='')
    data1 = [1,2,3]
    l=LinkList()
    l1=l.initList(data1)
    l.printlist(l1)
```

Comment: I guess you want your last element to point None as its next element, not to create an empty node.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want your last element to point None as its next element, not to create an empty node. Also, I believe the following approach would be a better practise to use in your classes:

```py
class Node():
 def __init__(self, data):
     self.next = None
     self.data = data
def Q2():
    class LinkList:
        def __init__(self):
            self.head=None
    
        def initList(self, data):
            self.head=start= Node(data[0])
            for i in data[1:]:
                start.next= Node(i)
                start=start.next
            
        def printlist(self):
            iterator = self.head
            while iterator:
                print(iterator.data,end="")
                iterator = iterator.next
            print()
            
        def duplicatelist(self):
            start=end=self.head
            while end.next:
                end=end.next
            temp=end
            while start != temp:
                end.next = Node(start.data)
                end = end.next
                start =start.next
            end.next= Node(start.data)
                
    data1 = [1,2,3,4]
    l=LinkList()
    l.initList(data1)
    l.printlist()
    l.duplicatelist()
    l.printlist()
    
Q2()
```

For example you don't need to give an input to printlist function since it can use self.head to print the list unless you want to start printing from a specific node.

Comment: On this basis, I defined a reverse function, but why: For example, input 123, output only 1

Comment: def reverselist(self):
            prev, curr = None, self.head
            while curr is not None:
                next = curr.next
                curr.next = prev
                prev = curr
                curr = next
            return prev
    l=LinkList()
    l.initList(data1)
    l.reverselist()
    l.printlist()

Answer (score 0):

If you define a more general data loading method that extends the content of the list with data from an iterable, you can use that method for both the initialization and the duplication of the list onto itself. If you name that method `__iadd__` and make it return self, you'll be able to use the += operator on your linked list.

Also, by defining the `__iter__()` special method, you make your list iterable so it can be used as a parameter to this extension method, and for printing the list:

```
class Node():
 def __init__(self, data):
     self.next = None
     self.data = data

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self,values=None):  # initialize with optional content
        self.head=None
        if values: self += values

    def __iter__(self):            # make the list iterable
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node.data
            node = node.next

    def __iadd__(self, values):      # support += operator
        # chain new nodes
        firstNew,lastNew = None,None     
        for i,value in enumerate(values):
            newNode = Node(value)
            if i: lastNew.next = newNode
            else: firstNew = newNode
            lastNew = newNode
        # add chain of new nodes to end of list
        tail = self.head
        while tail and tail.next: tail = tail.next
        if tail: tail.next = firstNew
        else:    self.head = firstNew
        return self         

    def __repr__(self):                  # representation for printing
        return ' '.join(map(str,self))
```

Extending the list onto itself:

```
data1 = [1,2,3]

L=LinkedList(data1)
print(L) # 1 2 3

L += L              
print(L) # 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Using two lists:

```
L1  = LinkedList(data1)
L2  = LinkedList(L1)
L2 += L1

print(L2) # 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thank u so much for u help. I have never learnt it before.